# Filter the inputText field in an alertDialog input

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to filter the access to an application only if the input Text written by the user ="123"

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder1=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                                builder1.setCancelable(true);
                                builder1.setTitle("Saisissez votre Code d'accès");
                                final EditText input = new EditText(context);
                                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

                                builder1.setView(input);
                                builder1.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                                        if(input.getText().toString()="123")
                                            upload(receivedUri, receivedUri.getPath(), targetPath, true);

                                        }

                                });
                                builder1.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                                                }
                                });
                               builder1.create();
                               builder1.show();
```

But it doesn't work , it displays the alertDialog but once i enter the password and click Ok it doesn't do anything else . How can i fix this? thanks

Comment: _input.getText().toString()="123"_ is totally wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FYI**

If you compare two Integers then use **==** & String compare to use **.equals()**

> The equals() method compares two objects for equality and returns true
>   if they are equal.

**Do not**

```
if(input.getText().toString()="123")
```

**Do**

```
 if(input.getText().toString().equals("123"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `input.getText().toString()="123"` to `input.getText().toString().equals("123")`